# Android highlight selected fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design

Hi guys I'm creating a navigation drawer, the navigation drawer is done but I need to highlight selected items. I'm confused with other tutorials need help.

[Need to highlight selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw6YJ.png)

This is the xml of navigation drawer:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="test.usmaan.alam.urdudictionarytest.Activities.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the background of navigation drawer item background as following

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

hen add the following part of code while clicking on the item

```
drawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
drawerList.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: Iam having an error cause i use Fragmentdrawer whichis not a listview